# Payflow Pro with Express Checkout - PayPal Manager Reporting

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, payflowpro

This is a general question.

I have implemented Payflow Pro with Transparent Redirect.  I have also implemented Express Checkout.  On my checkout page I would like to offer both options e.g. Pay Now OR Checkout with PayPal as is recommended by PayPal.  The thing is, if the user clicks Pay Now, Payflow is used to process the transaction which can then be viewed in the PayPal Manager account - Reports.  If the user clicks Checkout with PayPal then the transaction can only be viewed by going to the PayPal account.

How can I get the "Checkout with PayPal" transactions to show up in PayPal Manager?

There is a document here https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pfp_expresscheckout_pp.pdf whose name would seem to indicate that there is a Payflow Express Checkout process but it looks exactly like the regular Express Checkout process.  Am I missing something?

I think this may be related to using Test accounts.  I have a Manager account for testing Payflow, and I have a sandbox account for testing Express Checkout.  How do I use the same account for both?

Thanks

Comment: Ultimately this turned out to be a glitch with my PayPal Manager account.  This glitch was apparent in that the Hosted Pages - Set Up - had no Express checkout settings section.  Paypal had to fix the account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PayFlow manager credentials to create the `ExpressCheckout` Token (*EC-XXXXXXX*):

TENDER (Required) The tender type (method of payment). It is always P.

ACTION (Required) Is S to indicate this is a Set Express Checkout request.

```
USER=
VENDOR=
PARTNER=
PWD=
TRXTYPE=S
TENDER=P
ACTION=S
AMT=0.01
CURRENCY=USD
RETURNURL=http://ex.com
CANCELURL=http://ex.com
```

The response would be:

```
RESULT=0 
RESPMSG=Approved 
TOKEN=EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

You would redirect them the same way: http://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=*TOKEN*

Once they get directed back to your return url you get a `PAYERID`. Pass this with another request to complete the payment:

TOKEN (Required) The timestamped token that was returned in the Set Express 
Checkout response.

ACTION (Required) Is D to indicate this is a Set Express Checkout request.

PAYERID (Required) Unique PayPal buyer account identification number, as 
returned by Get Express Checkout Details response. This value is returned 
in the URL when the buyer is redirected to your website.

```
USER=
VENDOR=
PARTNER=
PWD=
TRXTYPE=S
TENDER=P
ACTION=D
AMT=0.01
CURRENCY=USD
TOKEN=
PAYERID=
```

Note that the email address you have on your Payflow account probably needs to be a valid sandbox account email address.

Comment: OK that helps.  I'm currently using the .net SDK for my EC calls and that does not support these options so I will have to recode the whole thing in order to test this.

Comment: If you are using the .NET Payflow or Payments Pro SDK: `PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.ECSetRequest`

Comment: OK I'll try that...I tried just now using PayflowNETAPI.SubmitTransaction to create the EC token and it did create a token but DoExpressCheckout did not like the token.

Comment: Once you have the token you would redirect them to the paypal website: http://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN. Once they come back it will give you the `payerid` in the GET variables. You need both the `payerid` and `token` to `DoExpressCheckout`

Comment: When I redirect to paypal I get "This transaction is invalid..."  My token doesn't start with "EC-" so its probably wrong.  Looking into ECSetRequest now, I found the object but haven't yet found any documentation or samples that use it and it doesn't have properties for things like USER so...

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to find much either. I disassembled the DLL using ILSpy as I don't have visual studio installed.

Comment: I found a demo that looks promising at http://www.markstraley.com/Code/PayFlowProExpressCheckout so I'm going to check that out

Comment: OK I implemented SetExpressCheckout using the Payflow API (including the ECSetRequest object) and the result I get is "25: not signed up for this tender type"  which leads me to think this is a problem with my paypal manager account